# Rails - How to display the time created like twitter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

please take a look here: http://twitter.com/#!/techcrunch

Notice that time is displayed with the following logic:

- If `created_at`, is under 24hrs, it display XXX hours ago, or 1 hour ago
- If `created_at`, is over 24hrs, it display the X Feb

Does Rails have this capability built in or is a helper needed? If so, what's the smart way to solve for this type of output?

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

You are probably looking for the [time_ago_in_words](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/DateHelper.html#method-i-time_ago_in_words) helper method.

Comment: Any way for that not to include "about" ?

Comment: This gives half the functionality, you would still have to handle the >24 hours case. A simple `if` may suffice.

Comment: `time_ago_in_words` uses `distance_of_time_in_words`. The source of the later may be found in `actionpack/lib/action_view/helpers/date_helper.rb`, line 66

Comment: @AnApprentice, it uses I18n translations which can be easily changed to whatever wording you want. See the distance_in_words part [here](https://github.com/svenfuchs/rails-i18n/blob/master/rails/locale/en-GB.yml) for the default format.

Answer (score 5):

i know this is a bit late but this is what i use in my view to display my messages:

```
<% if message.created_at > Time.now.beginning_of_day %>
    <%="#{time_ago_in_words(message.created_at)} ago"%> # 3 minutes ago, less than a minute ago  
<% else %>
    <%= message.created_at.strftime("%b %d, %Y") %> # Jun 29, 2012 
<% end %>
```

Can be extracted into a helper method. hope it helps